# Drupal 7: Working module anywhere for multi-step registration form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, registration, drupal-forms

Searched for a stable module that is good for a multi-step registration form so i can replace the built-in registration form of drupal with that one.

All i found were tutorials for the forms api of drupal but i need a module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think no one has made this because in most cases they are customized for a specific purpose, which yours probably is as well.

Comment: so i also have to use the forms api and write my own multi-step registration form?